# How can I use a PC's monitor output as an input in anoter PC?

Tags: video, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, video-conversion

I would like to make some real time video mixing setup where there will be multiple PCs creating CGI/graphic output and many cameras creating real life output that should be connected to a mixer PC that will broadcast the final output that will be mixed/edited with using all of these sources.

It would look like this:

[image]

I have all the hardware and software the only thing I'm missing is how can I connect/convert the graphic generating PC's monitor output as an input to the mixing PC?

Comment: A monitor cannot be input to a computer.  A monitor is an output.  There exist touch based monitors, those can be used, but it isn't clear if thats what you want.

Comment: @Ramhound I said "PCs monitor output" not "monitor's output". Also monitors are not outputs, they are peripherals. Finally, what I asked for can surly be done, just look down to the answer.

Comment: right a monitor is an peripherals which handles video output and display it on a screen.  Based on the accepted answer what you mean by "PCs monitor output" you mean the system's video output. You should have just said that.

Comment: @Ramhound Why? You just swapped PC with system which is a less exact term and monitor with video which doesn't make things more obvious either. With that expression you would have written "A video cannot be input to a computer". I clearly stated that I'm asking about a **PC's** output, the one that is related to monitors. I even drawn a picture to clarify things. If the question has a double-meaning for you why do you assume I ask about the nonsense one? BTW monitors can have output too if they are chainable so even that way the question would be still valid with the same goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for something called a [video capture card](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TV_tuner_card#Video_capture). In your case, you would need multiple capture cards to get the output from multiple PCs.

You would then need a [software vision mixer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_vision_mixer) to mix this into something you can output to monitors and/or the Internet. [Open Broadcaster Software](https://obsproject.com/) is a well-known (but by no means the only) mixer.

Comment: Thanks, I already had multiple software including the one you listed, I also had knowledge about TV tuner cards, I don't know why I haven't thought about video capture cards.